# How to add `--registry-mirror` when starting docker from "Docker quickstart terminal"?

Tags: configuration, proxy, docker, mirror

From the docker distribution document: https://github.com/docker/distribution

It says to configure the docker to use the mirror, we should:

```
Configuring the Docker daemon

You will need to pass the --registry-mirror option to your Docker daemon on startup:

docker --registry-mirror=https://<my-docker-mirror-host> daemon
```

I'm newbie to docker, and I start docker from mac normal by the provided "Docker Quickstart Termial" app, which actaully invokes a `start.sh` shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

VM=default
DOCKER_MACHINE=/usr/local/bin/docker-machine
VBOXMANAGE=/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage

BLUE='\033[0;34m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m'

unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH

clear

if [ ! -f $DOCKER_MACHINE ] || [ ! -f $VBOXMANAGE ]; then
  echo "Either VirtualBox or Docker Machine are not installed. Please re-run the Toolbox Installer and try again."
  exit 1
fi

$VBOXMANAGE showvminfo $VM &> /dev/null
VM_EXISTS_CODE=$?

if [ $VM_EXISTS_CODE -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Creating Machine $VM..."
  $DOCKER_MACHINE rm -f $VM &> /dev/null
  rm -rf ~/.docker/machine/machines/$VM
  $DOCKER_MACHINE create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 --virtualbox-disk-size 204800 $VM
else
  echo "Machine $VM already exists in VirtualBox."
fi

VM_STATUS=$($DOCKER_MACHINE status $VM)
if [ "$VM_STATUS" != "Running" ]; then
  echo "Starting machine $VM..."
  $DOCKER_MACHINE start $VM
  yes | $DOCKER_MACHINE regenerate-certs $VM
fi

echo "Setting environment variables for machine $VM..."
clear

cat << EOF


                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/


EOF
echo -e "${BLUE}docker${NC} is configured to use the ${GREEN}$VM${NC} machine with IP ${GREEN}$($DOCKER_MACHINE ip $VM)${NC}"
echo "For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com"
echo

eval $($DOCKER_MACHINE env $VM --shell=bash)

USER_SHELL=$(dscl /Search -read /Users/$USER UserShell | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1)
if [[ $USER_SHELL == *"/bash"* ]] || [[ $USER_SHELL == *"/zsh"* ]] || [[ $USER_SHELL == *"/sh"* ]]; then
  $USER_SHELL --login
else
  $USER_SHELL
fi
```

Is it the correct file that I can put my '--registry-mirror' config to it? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `docker-machine create --help`:

```
docker-machine create --help
Usage: docker-machine create [OPTIONS] [arg...]

Create a machine.

Run 'docker-machine create --driver name' to include the create flags for that driver in the help text.

Options:
...
   --engine-insecure-registry [--engine-insecure-registry option --engine-insecure-registry option]     Specify insecure registries to allow with the created en
gine
   --engine-registry-mirror [--engine-registry-mirror option --engine-registry-mirror option]           Specify registry mirrors to use
```

So you can modify your script to add one more parameter:

```
--engine-registry-mirror=...
```

However, since your '`default`' docker-machine probably already exists (do a `docker-machine ls`), you might need to remove it first (`docker-machine rm default`: make sure you can easily recreate your images from your local Dockerfiles, and/or that you don't have data container that would need to be saved first)

Comment: Would it be possible to update the registry used by the default machine rather than having to (re)create a new one?

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland 5 years later, I am not too usre: that would be a good question on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Open `C:\Users\<YourName>\.docker\daemon.json`, edit the "registry-mirrors" entry in that file.

[image]

```js
{"registry-mirrors":["https://registry.docker-cn.com"],"insecure-registries":[], "debug":true, "experimental": true}
```