# regenerating certificates hangs on windows 7

Tags: ssl, docker, virtualbox, windows-7-x64

I'm a total docker newbie and tried to get it working on my windows 7 64-bit machine.
The installation went okay, but the "Docker Quickstart Terminal" will not start up as expected. It seems to hang when trying to create the SSH key:

```
(default) Downloading https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v
(default) 0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1
Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue...
```

so I tried to regenerate the certificates in a cmd window and also this does not work:

```
>docker-machine regenerate-certs default

Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): y
Regenerating TLS certificates
Detecting the provisioner...
OS type not recognized
```

I've tried to deactivate my virus scanner and execute the cmd windows as admin without success.

Any ideas what to check? Are there any interesting logfiles?

here's the `docker version` output:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://localhost:2375/v1.21/version: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: 
ConnectEx tcp: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Comment: I found useful look at the logs of the oracle virtual box (and also trying to start manually the machine "default")

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have hyper-v activated (that is more a [Windows 10 issue](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2502)), and if [your BIOS VT-X/AMD-v is enabled](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2502), then something else went wrong.

If `docker-machine ls` still lists the `default` machine, delete it: `docker-machine rm default`.

If you had (previous to your docker-toolbox installation) a VirtualBox already installed, try and:

- uninstall completely VirtualBox
- in `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\`, find and delete these five files (there may be less left, that is ok, delete them anyway):

  - `vboxdrv.sys`,
  - `vboxnetadp.sys`,
  - `vboxnetflt.sys`,
  - `vboxusbmon.sys`,
  - `vboxusb.sys`.
- in `regedit`, key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\`, delete these 5 folders (there may be less left, that is ok, delete them anyway):

  - `VBoxDrv`,
  - `VBoxNetAdp`,
  - `VBoxNetFlt`,
  - `VBoxUSBMon`,
  - `VBoxUSB`.

Then reinstall the latest VirtualBox.

Make sure:

- you have the [latest `docker-machine`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases) copied somewhere in your PATH (the 0.5.3 has been released 22 hours ago: [`releases/download/v0.5.3/docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.5.3/docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe)).
- `%HOME%` is defined (typically to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`)

From there, try [manually to recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34262775/6309) the default machine [like the quick-start script did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34261005/6309):

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 --virtualbox-disk-size 204800 default
eval $($DOCKER_MACHINE env my_new_container --shell=bash)
docker-machine ssh my_new_container
```

Comment: unfortunately, that did not help in my case.

Comment: @MartinTrummer I'll leave my answer there, as it has helped me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I've now tried to create a Linux VM directly in VirtualBox and start it from there: also gets some time-out. So I think it's not related to docker.

I've found a VirtualBox bug-report that says, that this can happen when you have Avira installed.

Here's a discussion about the issue on the [Avira forum](https://avira.ideascale.com/a/dtd/Avira-sollte-das-Ausf%C3%BChren-von-VMs-in-Virtualbox-nicht-blocken/160234-26744#idea-tab-comments) - unfortunatly mostly in German.

One paragraph indicates that it may help to deactivate "Advanced process protection":

> Configuration -> General -> Security and disable the option "Advanced
>   process protection". Click "Apply" and restart the device. You should
>   be able to run your VM in VirtualBox after that.

In my case this does not help, so I'll need to wait for a fix or completely uninstall Avira.

Comment: I found the completely procedure for deactivating the Avira driver that gives problems (avipbb) here https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=67840&p=347563&hilit=avira#p347694 , after that docker toolbox installed in a breeze!

Answer (score -1):

> (defualt) DBG | Getting to WaitForSSH function...
>   (defualt) DBG | Using SSH client type: external
>   (defualt) DBG | &{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@127.0.0.1 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i C:\Users\Ming.docker\machine\machines\defualt\id_rsa -p 58549] C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin\ssh.exe }
>   (defualt) DBG | About to run SSH command:
>   (defualt) DBG | exit 0
>   (defualt) DBG | SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255:
>   (defualt) DBG | Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : Something went wrong running an SSH command!
>   (defualt) DBG | command : exit 0
>   (defualt) DBG | err     : exit status 255
>   (defualt) DBG | output  :

Comment: Could you elaborate on that answer please ;-) ? 8 months after the question has been asked, a bit of context and why this is a viable answer might be in place. Thanks